# How to Resolve Angular Scope Variable Inside Div Class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-directive

```
<div class="progressMain">
    <div class="stocking progressWrap progress" data-progress-percent="33">
       <div class="progressBar progress stocking"></div>
       <div class="progressText">In Progress 3 of 7 steps</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have data-progress-percent value in my directive scope but I am not sure how I can resolve scope value inside data-progress-percent. 
I tried data-progress-percent={{value}} but it didn't work.
Any idea how I can resolve scope variable inside div class ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$timeout()`. It will solve your problem.
`$timeout()` will run in the next `$digest` cycle.

Comment: is this a $timeout problem ? I want to resolve angular variable inside div class.

Comment: it is not a $timeout problem .. whatever changes that you made inside $timeout will run at last of $digest cycle .. so if you want to complete cycle first then you can use it, when using $timeout will make you out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Have a `scope` variable in your controller to be passed to your `directive`. Then use directive `template` to display the percent value(may be after some calculation in your directive link's function).

**DEMO** - **http://plnkr.co/edit/8DZzSjcpDqRworpxQrAs**

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
     <div class="progressMain">
        <div class="stocking progressWrap progress" progress-percent="percentValue">
        </div>
     </div>

     <br/><br/>
     <div>Enter percentage value to be passed to directive and used as in directive template:</div>
     <br/>
     <input type="text" ng-model="percentValue" />
</body>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.percentValue = 33;
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.directive('progressPercent', function () {
  return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div class="progressBar progress stocking"></div><div class="progressText">In Progress {{percentValue}} steps</div>'
  };
});
```

Hope it helps.